# Raw socket sendto failed using C on Linux

Tags: c, udp, raw-sockets, sendto

I'm trying to send a **raw packet** using UDP, with the IP and UDP headers that I have constructed in my code. Raw packet successfully initialized with `socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)` and socket option set using `setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(int))`.

The problem is when I send the packet using `sendto()`, I get the error 'Message too long'.

My IP header is 20 bytes and UDP header 8 bytes and my data is 12 bytes. So the total is only 40 bytes. This can't possibly be too long for a single UDP packet. Can someone help?

The type of `val` is a pointer to an `int`

Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

//The packet length in byes
#define PCKT_LEN 50

//Date size in bytes
#define DATA_SIZE 12

//PseudoHeader struct used to calculate UDP checksum.
typedef struct PseudoHeader{    
    unsigned long int source_ip;
    unsigned long int dest_ip;
    unsigned char reserved;
    unsigned char protocol;
    unsigned short int udp_length;
}PseudoHeader;

// Ripped from Richard Stevans Book
unsigned short ComputeChecksum(unsigned char *data, int len)
{
    long sum = 0;  /* assume 32 bit long, 16 bit short */
    unsigned short *temp = (unsigned short *)data;

    while(len > 1){
        sum += *temp++;
        if(sum & 0x80000000)   /* if high order bit set, fold */
            sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);
        len -= 2;
    }

    if(len)       /* take care of left over byte */
        sum += (unsigned short) *((unsigned char *)temp);

    while(sum>>16)
        sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);

    return ~sum;
}

int BindRawSocketToInterface(int rawsock, char *addr, short int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in s_addr;
    s_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr);
    s_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if((bind(rawsock, (struct sockaddr *)&s_addr, sizeof(s_addr)))== -1)
    {
        perror("Error binding raw socket to interface\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 1;
}


// Fabricate the IP header or we can use the
// standard header structures but assign our own values.
struct ip *CreateIPHeader(char *srcip, char *destip)
{
    struct ip *ip_header;

    ip_header = (struct ip *)malloc(sizeof(struct ip));

    ip_header->ip_v = 4;
    ip_header->ip_hl = 5;
    ip_header->ip_tos = 0;
    ip_header->ip_len = htons(sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + DATA_SIZE);
    ip_header->ip_id = htons(111);
    ip_header->ip_off = 0;
    ip_header->ip_ttl = 111;
    ip_header->ip_p = IPPROTO_TCP;
    ip_header->ip_sum = 0; /* We will calculate the checksum later */
    inet_pton(AF_INET, srcip, &ip_header->ip_src);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, destip, &ip_header->ip_dst);

    /* Calculate the IP checksum now : 
    The IP Checksum is only over the IP header */
    ip_header->ip_sum = ComputeChecksum((unsigned char *)ip_header, ip_header->ip_hl*4);

    return (ip_header);
}

// Creates a the UDP header.
struct udphdr *CreateUdpHeader(char *srcport, char *destport )
{
    struct udphdr *udp_header;

    /* Check netinet/udp.h for header definiation */

    udp_header = (struct udphdr *)malloc(sizeof(struct udphdr));

    udp_header->source = htons(atoi(srcport));
    udp_header->dest = htons(atoi(destport));
    udp_header->len = htons(sizeof(struct udphdr) + DATA_SIZE); //TODO: need to specify this
    udp_header->check = htons(0);

    return (udp_header);
}

void CreatePseudoHeaderAndComputeUdpChecksum(struct udphdr *udp_header, struct ip *ip_header, unsigned char *data)
{
    /*The TCP Checksum is calculated over the PseudoHeader + TCP header +Data*/

    /* Find the size of the TCP Header + Data */
    int segment_len = ntohs(ip_header->ip_len) - ip_header->ip_hl*4; 

    /* Total length over which TCP checksum will be computed */
    int header_len = sizeof(PseudoHeader) + segment_len;

    /* Allocate the memory */

    unsigned char *hdr = (unsigned char *)malloc(header_len);

    /* Fill in the pseudo header first */

    PseudoHeader *pseudo_header = (PseudoHeader *)hdr;

    pseudo_header->source_ip = ip_header->ip_src.s_addr;
    pseudo_header->dest_ip = ip_header->ip_dst.s_addr;
    pseudo_header->reserved = 0;
    pseudo_header->protocol = ip_header->ip_p;
    pseudo_header->udp_length = htons(segment_len);


    /* Now copy TCP */

    memcpy((hdr + sizeof(PseudoHeader)), (void *)udp_header, 8);

    /* Now copy the Data */

    memcpy((hdr + sizeof(PseudoHeader) + 8), data, DATA_SIZE);

    /* Calculate the Checksum */

    udp_header->check = ComputeChecksum(hdr, header_len);

    /* Free the PseudoHeader */
    free(hdr);
}

// Source IP, source port, target IP, target port from the command line arguments
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sd;
    char buffer[PCKT_LEN];
    char *data = "Hello World!";

    // Source and destination addresses: IP and port
    struct sockaddr_in to_addr;
    int one = 1;
    const int *val = &one;

    printf("IP Header Size: %lu \n", sizeof(struct ip));
    printf("UDP Header Size: %lu \n", sizeof(struct udphdr));
    printf("Data Size: %d\n", DATA_SIZE);
    printf("IP Total: %lu \n", sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + DATA_SIZE);

    memset(buffer, 0, PCKT_LEN);

    if(argc != 5)
    {
        printf("- Invalid parameters!!!\n");
        printf("- Usage %s <source hostname/IP> <source port> <target hostname/IP> <target port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Create a raw socket with UDP protocol
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if(sd < 0)
    {
        perror("socket() error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
        printf("socket() - Using SOCK_RAW socket and UDP protocol is OK.\n");

    //Bind the socket to the source address and port.
    BindRawSocketToInterface(sd, argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));

    // Inform the kernel do not fill up the packet structure. we will build our own...
    if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt() error");
        close(sd);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
        printf("setsockopt() is OK.\n");


    // The source is redundant, may be used later if needed
    // The address family
    to_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    to_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[3]);
    to_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[4]));

    //Create the IP header.
    struct ip *ip_header = CreateIPHeader(argv[1], argv[3]);
    //Create the UDP header.
    struct udphdr *udp_header = CreateUdpHeader(argv[2], argv[4]);
    //Compute UDP checksum
    CreatePseudoHeaderAndComputeUdpChecksum(udp_header, ip_header, (unsigned char*)data);

    //Copy IP header, UDP header, and data to the packet buffer.
    memcpy(buffer, ip_header, sizeof(struct ip));
    memcpy(buffer + sizeof(struct ip), udp_header, 8 /*sizeof(struct udphdr)*/);
    memcpy(buffer + sizeof(struct ip) + 8, data, DATA_SIZE);

    printf("Using raw socket and UDP protocol\n");
    printf("Using Source IP: %s port: %u, Target IP: %s port: %u.\n", argv[1], atoi(argv[2]), argv[3], atoi(argv[4]));


    if(sendto(sd, buffer, htons(20)/*ip_header->ip_len*/, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&to_addr, sizeof(to_addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("sendto() error");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("sendto() is OK.\n");
    }

    free(ip_header);
    free(udp_header);
    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: show the code that does this (and in your setsockopt, what's the type of `val` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(sendto(sd, buffer, htons(20)/*ip_header->ip_len*/, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&to_addr, sizeof(to_addr)) < 0)
```

The length here is wrong, you should not specify that in network byte order.

A simple 20 is enough. htons(20) will be a very large number on a little endian machine.
( if you want to send other things that just the IP header, you should include that too in the length,, sounds like your buffer is 40 bytes, not 20)

Comment: nos, thank you for the solution. The sendto now return ok and I believe the packet is now sent through the network. I now run into another problem that the packet is not received at the destination host (my server). Do you think it could be something wrong with the format of my UDP datagram?

Comment: Verify with wireshark, it's usually good at pointing out errors in packets. The checksum might be a culprit, make sure that it really is right. You're setting IPPROTO_TCP, shouldn't that be IPPROTO_UDP ?

Comment: I changed IPPROTO_TCP to IPPROTO_UDP and the packet when through. I also thought about inspecting the packet using Wireshark, but you just saved me a few hours of work. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use my own function that i don't have your problem:

```
    #define NDEBUG
#define COUNTMAX 3000
#define   MAX_FAKE 100
#define   ERROR    -1
#define   TYPE_A   1
#define   TYPE_PTR 12
#define   CLASS_INET 1
#define ERROR -1

#ifndef IPVERSION
  #define IPVERSION 4
#endif                  /* IPVERISON */

#ifndef IP_MAXPACKET
  #define IP_MAXPACKET 65535
#endif                  /* IP_MAXPACKET */

#define DNSHDRSIZE 12

#ifndef IP_MAXPACKET
#define IP_MAXPACKET 65535
#endif                   /* IP_MAXPACKET */

#define   IPHDRSIZE     sizeof(struct iphdr)
#define   UDPHDRSIZE    sizeof(struct udphdr)
    int udp_send(int s, unsigned long saddr, unsigned long daddr,unsigned short sport,unsigned short dport,char *datagram, unsigned datasize) 
{
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    struct   iphdr   *ip;
    struct   udphdr  *udp;
    unsigned char    *data;
    unsigned char    packet[4024];


    ip     = (struct iphdr     *)packet; 
    udp    = (struct udphdr    *)(packet+IPHDRSIZE);
    data   = (unsigned char    *)(packet+IPHDRSIZE+UDPHDRSIZE);

    memset(packet,0,sizeof(packet));

    udp->source  = htons(sport); 
    udp->dest    = htons(dport);
    udp->len     = htons(UDPHDRSIZE+datasize);
    udp->check   = 0;         

    memcpy(data,datagram,datasize);

    ip->saddr.s_addr  = saddr;
    ip->daddr.s_addr  = daddr;
    ip->version  = 4;             /*ip version*/
    ip->ihl      = 5;
    ip->ttl      = 245;
    ip->id       = random()%5985;
    ip->protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;   /*protocol type*/
    ip->tot_len  = htons((IPHDRSIZE + UDPHDRSIZE + datasize));
    ip->check    = 0;
    ip->check    = in_cksum((char *)packet,IPHDRSIZE);

    sin.sin_family=AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr=daddr;
    sin.sin_port=udp->dest;
        printf ("socket: %d, packet: %s,size: %d, struct addr: %p, size: %i", s, packet, IPHDRSIZE+UDPHDRSIZE+datasize, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    return sendto(s, packet, IPHDRSIZE+UDPHDRSIZE+datasize, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
}// end of udp_send function
```

Answer (score -1):

The call to sendto() doesn't appear to be right as shown, even corrected per the comments:
Original:  sendto(sd, buffer, htons(20)/*ip_header->ip_len*/,...);
Orr as corrected:  sendto(sd, buffer, 20/*ip_header->ip_len*/,...);
The data length parameter should be the sum of header and data lengths:  20+8+12 = 40.  A general solution could be:
sendto(sd, buffer, sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + DATA_SIZE,...);
With this change it started working for me.